# Air Elemental Whirlwind: Can It Damage A Creature Multiple Times?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, elementals

As stated in the title, I'm wondering if an air elemental's whirlwind can damage a creature multiple times. Being as air elementals (and water elementals, since they can become a vortex) have such a high movement in their respective elements, could a whirlwind damage a creature, drop it off, move away, then come back and hit it again?

Comment: A few of these are pretty tightly related, but I think other portions of it should be split up to be their own question(s). Specifically, I would ask 1) if the creature can be attacked while its a whirlwind/vortex, if vortexes inherit the debris effect, and if they have concealment, then separately 2) if they could attack any number of creatures and if it can affect the same creature twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I have to look, might edit in an answer later, sorry.
2. Seems like no, there is no limit.

> The whirlwind can have only as many creatures trapped inside at one time as will fit inside the whirlwind’s volume. The whirlwind can eject any carried creatures whenever it wishes as a free action, depositing them in its space.

So it looks like a whirlwind can dump creatures before it reaches it max so that it can affect a new target.

3. No, you can't run over creatures multiple times in the same turn. An example that gets to the spirit, is the flaming sphere spell. It has language that keeps it from being able to move over the same target multiple times. It ends the sphere's action in the case of that spell, but I feel like it implies that the answer to your question is no.
4. Yes, if the vortex touches a solid surface under the water it should create the swirling debris. The debris field would not extend beyond the water.
5. Yes the debris field should give total concealment for a 50% miss chance. This miss chance should affect the elemental and any creatures within it.

Comment: Have to disagree with your 3 answer...nothing in the ability description implies it only works once a round or turn on a given target.

Comment: ParasocialTroop's "No run over creatures multiple times" is right. It's like Grapple, you don't apply Grapple damage the round it is initiated. You can't grapple the same creature more than once in a round. You apply damage on round 2+ of a grapple if you maintain it. Same mechanic, different appearance.

Comment: I don't see how a spell that specifically disallows running over a target multiple times has any bearing on a monster rule that completely lacks any of the guidelines mentioned in that spell.

Comment: Apologies @lfusaso it appears I either misread the question or got it confused with a related question and didn't see the movement rate component. According to Whirlwind (Su) each time the creature is 'contacted' or 'suspended' it takes slam damage. Multiple 'contact' damage seems feasible, but to lift into the air should take a round as damage is calculated round by round, so you probably shouldn't be able to do multiple 'suspended' slam attacks a round not matter what the movement is.